# Find words in array values

Tags: php, arrays

A image uploader allows max 10 images to upload.

The user have to add a image name example: "Nice porsche 911 in blue".

When the image name contains specific words like "own, my" there should come a error message.

Therefore I have to search the array sentences (image name) for specific words.

When there is only 1 $variable (string) I know what to do:

```
if (strpos($image_name,'own') !== false) OR (strpos($image_name,'my') !== false)) 
{
$error = 'Dont use words like my, own etc.';
}
```

How to do the same for the array $image_names? The array can have 1-10 values. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the array:

```
foreach($image_names as $image_name){
    if (strpos($image_name,'own') !== false) OR (strpos($image_name,'my') !== false)) 
    {
        $error = 'Dont use words like my, own etc.';
    }
}
```